# Change jquery code from targeting a value to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i got this html code with a drop down list where i select the option blue or green, and it works great with the jquery below.

```
<select id="styleSelect">
    <option value="styleblue">Blue</option>
    <option value="stylegreen">Green</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
  $("#styleSelect").change(function() {
       updateStyleSheet($(this).val());
  });
```

My question is how to change this code into a clickable link instead of an option value, i already now the html code should be like this

```
<div id="styleSelect">
<a href="styleblue">click here</a>
<a href="stylegreen">click here</a>
</div>
```

But how should the jquery look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#styleSelect a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   updateStyleSheet($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("#styleSelect a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop link
    var href = this.href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#styleSelect a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  updateStyleSheet($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="styleSelect">
  <a href="styleblue">click here</a>
  <a href="stylegreen">click here</a>
</div>
```